# Fechar modal JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Preciso fazer o meu `deleteConfirmationModal` fechar.
Só funciona ao clicar no **NÃO**.

Preciso fazer ele executar a ação do **SIM** e fechar o modal.

```
<p:commandLink title="#{label.REMOVE}" process="@this" styleClass="btn-remove" oncomplete="deleteConfirmationModal.show();"/>
<p:confirmDialog message="#{label.DELETE_CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE}"
                 header="#{label.HEADER_DELETE_CONFIRMATION_MODAL}" severity="alert"
                 widgetVar="deleteConfirmationModal" id="deleteConfirmationModalId">
    <p:commandLink value="#{label.YES}"
                   oncomplete="deleteConfirmationModal.hide();"
                   action="#{controller.actionRemove(item)}"
                   styleClass="btn-save"
                   id="buttonYesOption"
                   update="@form, deleteConfirmationModalId">
    </p:commandLink>
    <p:commandLink value="#{label.NOT}"
                   onclick="deleteConfirmationModal.hide()"
                   styleClass="btn-cancel"
                   id="buttonNotOption" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do Primefaces que você está usando? Maior que a 5?

Comment: Solução postada 2 minutos após a pergunta?

Comment: Qual o problema? O site permite realizar perguntas com soluções.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adicionei o `onclick="deleteConfirmationModal.hide()"` no botão **SIM**

Comment: Acho que essa não é a melhor forma de fazer isso.. O `oncomplete` provavelmente funcione se você fizer `oncomplete="PF('deleteConfirmationModal').hide()"`

Comment: vou tentar fazer isso.

Comment: Legal! Isso vai funcionar se a versão do prime for > 5

Comment: Solução postada 2 minutos após a pergunta?

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿ Isso não tem problema (do ponto de vista do site). Mas a resposta poderia ser melhor elaborada

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿ o site permite realizar perguntas com soluções.